# No such file or directory error when running Mahout classification on 20newsgroup data

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, mahout

So I am still really new to Mahout and I want to learn. I have Hadoop version 2.3.7 and Mahout 0.12 running on my machine. I am trying to understand how classification works on Mahout from [this tutorial](https://mahout.apache.org/users/classification/twenty-newsgroups.html) about "Twenty Newsgroups Classification Example".

I am running this command from Mahout directory.

```
./examples/bin/classify-20newsgroups.sh
```

and choose the first option (cnaivebayes-MapReduce) to run Naive Bayes classification. But I got this error like this.

```
Extracting...
tar (child): ../20news-bydate.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
+ echo 'Preparing 20newsgroups data'
Preparing 20newsgroups data
+ rm -rf /tmp/mahout-work-lia/20news-all
+ mkdir /tmp/mahout-work-lia/20news-all
+ cp -R '/tmp/mahout-work-lia/20news-bydate/*/*' /tmp/mahout-work-lia/20news-all
cp: cannot stat '/tmp/mahout-work-lia/20news-bydate/*/*': No such file or directory
```

The `/tmp/mahout-work-lia/20news-bydate` directory does exist, I have checked. Hadoop is also running just fine. So what did I do wrong? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does it exist on your local machine or in HDFS?

Comment: @rawkintrevo hey there, thanks for the response. I finally figured out the cause of this problem. I cleared out the temp directory and run it again using faster internet connection and it worked! So I guess the problem was caused by my slow internet connection, which sucks because I don't have fast connection all the time.